# How to prove that local isometries can shrink but not increase intrinsic distance? (Differential geometry)

Tags: differential-geometry, isometry

I am trying to think through the following problem, but I'm totally at a loss and can't imagine a surface that would be a valid example. The question is,

**"Give an example and a proof to show: Local isometries can shrink but not increase intrinsic distance."**

The given definition of local isometry is:

**A local isometry F: M-->N of surfaces is a mapping that preserves dot products of tangent vectors (that is, F* does).**

Here F* is the derivative map of F.

Any ideas? I really really struggle with this material, so if you could offer anything it would be so helpful!

Comment: How much differential geometry do you know?

Comment: Do you know of two SIMPLE surfaces that are locally isometric, but not globally isometric?

Comment: Not a lot :( Hmmmmm....would an example be a plane and a cylinder?

Comment: One detail to ponder is, how is distance _defined_ in a surface? Could a local isometry increase distance? Your example is good.

Comment: In the textbook, it defines the intrinsic distance between two points (say, p and q) as the shortest possible length of a curve on the surface that connects p and q. It then says local isometries preserve dot products of tangent vectors...but I'm not sure how it could be possible to make the distance shorter? Or longer, for that matter.

Comment: So think about your example, and think about what preserving dot products of tangent vectors tells you about lengths of curves and their images.

Comment: The question is about 2D, but I think a 1D example can show us what's going on. Take the map $S(0,1) \to S(0,1)$ (between cirles in $\mathbb{C}$) given by $z \mapsto z^2$, or even better the map $S(0,2) \to S(0,1)$ given by $z \mapsto z^2/4$.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what preserving dot products says about curve length...could you give me a hint?